# Easiest way to do SSLSocketServer (certificate generation at runtime)

Tags: java, security, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I want a simple way to create a SSLServerSocket. I would like for a self-signed certificate to be generated and used at runtime because the data needs to be protected, but it isn't super important that it is very, very secure.

I found tutorials on making an SSLServerSocket but they assume that you had a proper certificate.

Psuedo-code, code examples and a simple paragraph are all acceptable answers.

Comment: Why do you have to create it at runtime? You only need one for the lifetime of the server, modulo ciertifcate expiry.

Comment: sure, but it has to be made at runtime at least once...

Comment: Hmm.. good question. Wonder how complicated the generation is? I guess it's along the lines of finding very large prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it may be invoking an external program. `openssl` is a great tool for many encryption things... Make a self signed cert with:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:1024 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout www.example.com.pem  -out www.example.com.pem
```

You could run such generation with `Runtime.exec()` or using a `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: this is an embedded server that needs to work cross platform. is there no way that it can be done with java?

Answer (score 0):

Normally self-signed certificate has no sense at all if it's generated on each run of the server. It's better to create a self-signed certificate once (during server setup, for example) and that's all.

There's a good description and discussion of self-signed certificates for securing communication [in this StackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327309/can-using-self-signed-certificates-with-wcf-be-secure/4327446#4327446). Please read it as well, as it addresses your question too.